# React mouse events fired on components not listening for them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Not sure if it's my profound misunderstanding of React events or an actual bug, but mouse events registered on the parents sometimes fire on the children.

In the bin below, mousing around the two divs will eventually result in the inner div getting highlighted red, even though it doesn't have an event trigger for attaching the ui-hover class (though its parent does).

http://jsbin.com/vemopo/1/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to depend on how fast the mouse is moving. My guess is, `event.target` becomes whatever is under the mouse when the event is triggered. So it fires when entering the parent div, but if the mouse is moving quickly then it may already be hovering the child div when the event handler is processed.

(Updated answer)

As @Stan commented, replacing `event.target` with `event.currentTarget` is the simplest fix, it will target the element whose listener triggered the event rather than the element under the mouse.

(Original answer / other options)

You can also set `ref="target"` on the parent div and then use the ref rather than the event target.

```
_mouseEnter: function(event) {
  this.refs.target.getDOMNode().classList.add('ui-hover');
},
```

However, it may be preferable to avoid touching the DOM like this. In that case you could use setState in the event handlers and use conditionals to give a different result depending on `this.state`.

```
_mouseEnter: function(event) {
  this.setState({
    hovering: true
  });
}
```

Comment: I think the right solution is actually to use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`, since I want to modify the element that's actually processing the event. You're right in that it seems that when the mouse is moving quickly the target may get updated to the inner element, but the currentTarget that triggered the event should always stay put.